# Auto Set fields with $scope variables - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

aving trouble filling text field and pre select a dropdown.

This is my angular code.

```
angular.module('MyCtrl', [])


    .controller('myController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
                $scope.user = {};
                $scope.master = {};
            $scope.user.name='Fahad'; //this text field and is not working
            $scope.user.gender='Male'; //this is select and also not working

      $scope.update = function(user) {
           //... some code that take all the user fields and update to DB
       };
      $scope.reset = function() {
         $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
      };
     $scope.reset();
    }]);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="uName">
<select ng-model="user.gender" name="mType" required>
   <option value="Male" selected="selected">Male</option>
   <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Everything else is fine.
update function takes all the text fields and update,

but for some reason i need to have some fields pre-filled.

Thanks for hlep.

Comment: are you referencing the controller into your HTML ? `<div ng-controller="myController">`

Comment: Yes... Thats not the problem for sure..

Comment: It looks simple the code, but may be I am missing something and not getting to it..

Comment: I guess you should provide more code snippet because your actual code looks right to me

Comment: ok, let me edit... actually i don't think there will be any issue.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle/plunkr for the problem so that we can visualize the issue

Comment: whats wrong with the fiddle now. http://jsfiddle.net/7b6ed4ga/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the first line, You are trying to bootstrap angular using ng-Model. It should be ng-app and all fits into place after that :)

HTML Code:

```
//Over here change ng-model to ng-app
<div ng-app="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="uName">
        <select ng-model="user.gender" name="mType" required>
            <option value="Male" selected="selected">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
        <button ng-click="update(masjid)">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7b6ed4ga/2/)

Comment: Looks fine there in fiddle...
But not working for me...
I am already using ng-app

Comment: there must be a typo in your code...you need to double check or best have the complete code in the fiddle

Comment: hmmm.. Code is dynamically generated  actually.
 One thing, I using <body ng-app="User"> in header.php that is included, then <div ng-controller="myController"> text fields </div>in user.php

Comment: Oops... $scope.reset(); was the issues that was called at the end of the controller.